# Further speeding up openmp reduction loop

Tags: c, openmp

Is there a better way to perform reduction operation or further improving the performance of this code. Should I use the collapse clause ?.
MAX just finds the maximum between the two and EPS is just a floating point number and fdm is a structure

```
 void cal_beta(float *beta, float **gd0, float **gd1, float **cg, fdm2d fdm)
/*< calculate beta for nonlinear conjugate gradient algorithm >*/
{
   int ix,iz;
   float a, b, c ;
   a=0.0,b=0.0,c=0.0 ;
   #ifdef _OPENMP       
   #pragma omp parallel for  private(ix,iz)         \
       schedule(static,fdm->ompchunk) shared(gd0,gd1,cg)    \
       reduction(+:a,b,c)                           
   #endif           
    for(ix=0;ix<fdm->nxpad;ix++){
        for(iz=0;iz<fdm->nzpad;iz++){
            a+=gd1[ix][iz]*(gd1[ix][iz]-gd0[ix][iz]);
            b+=cg[ix][iz]*(gd1[ix][iz]-gd0[ix][iz]);
            c+=gd1[ix][iz]*gd1[ix][iz];
        }           
    }
    float beta_HS=0.0;
    float beta_DY=0.0;
    if(fabs(b)>EPS) 
   {
    beta_HS=a/b; 
    beta_DY=c/b;

    } 
   *beta=MAX(0.0, MIN(beta_HS, beta_DY));/* Hybrid HS-DY method combined with iteration restart */

}
```

Comment: Why haven't you used the *const* modifier on any of the parameters? (Just bad style, not a technical problem.) What value has `fdm->ompchunk`? And what are typical values for `fdm->nxpad` and `fdm->nzpad`? Any specific reason for manually providing the chunk size at all, instead of using the thread count dependent heuristic?

Comment: 'fdm->nxpad' and 'fdm->nzpad' varies from 200 to 800 and 'fdm->ompchunk' is 1 at the moment

Comment: The latter one would be a problem. The default would have been `fdm->nxpad / num_threads`. With the value you chose, the scheduling overhead eliminates the performance gains entirely. You could also further try to use thread-local variables to point to the individual rows of `cg`, `gd0`, `gd1`, to avoid the double de-reference in the inner loop (in case the compiler isn't resolving that properly).

Comment: You may wish to achieve simd reduction in the inner loop as well as parallel reduction in the outer loop.  Depending on your compiler, this might be promoted by separate inner and outer reduction variables and omp directives and may require additional compile options.

Comment: so should I use schedule(dynamic) instead ?

Comment: @tim18 I am using gcc compiler . Could you please refer to me an example ? I am open to SIMD intrinsincs

Comment: `schedule(static)` is fine, just don't override the default chunk size. You probably won't need SIMD intrinsics, just use thread local variables to point to invidiual rows of your fields, and the compiler might use them for you automatically.

Comment: Without that OpenMP pragma at least GCC should have fully vectorized both inner and outer loop without local vars, but the auto-vectorization is easily thrown off by the glue code added by OpenMP. If you add them, it should match on the inner loop at least. Similar for Clang AFAIK.

Comment: I'd recommend you to declare the pointers you pass to this routines as `restrict` if possible. That will ensure that the compiler will have more optimization opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the `collapse` clause to merge the two loops into a single parallel loop region. According to the [OpenMP 4.5 manual](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/openmp-4.5.pdf) in page 58, lines 25-29:

> The **collapse** clause may be used to specify how many loops are
>   associated with the loop 26 construct. The parameter of the collapse
>   clause must be a constant positive integer expression. 27 If a
>   collapse clause is specified with a parameter value greater than 1,
>   then the iterations of the 28 associated loops to which the clause
>   applies are collapsed into one larger iteration space that is then 29
>   divided according to the schedule clause